# Problemas com cadastro de dados com listagem do ComboBox e função

Tags: delphi, funções, combobox

Eu estou com grandes dificuldades com o comboBox e o uso de function no delphi

Eu peço desculpas, sou iniciante no mundo da programação e não conseguir identar o código aqui, vou deixar o código no pastebin.

código:
https://pastebin.com/Z1Z540Hd

está dando erro na linha 49:
"Not enough actual parameters"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia kingarthur.. tudo certinho?:)
Cara .. se eu entendi corretamente o que acontece é o seguinte..:
**cmbNomes = TCombobox**... correto?
Na linha abaixo voce quer colocar dentro do combobox o valor da propriedade nome do objeto objdados.. correto?
 **cmbNomes.Items.AddObject(objdados.nome);**
Se é isso o modo correto é esse..: cmbNomes.Items.Add(objdados.nome);

A funçao que tu esta querendo usar AddObject pede dois parametros..
**1º Parametro-** String.. Seria o ..: objdados.nome como você fez..
**2º Parametro-** TObject
Um Modo de usar essa função seria para passar no segundo parâmetro o ID da pessoa..
Ficaria assim
`cmbNomes.Items.Add(objdados.nome,TObject(objdados.id_pessoa));`
Para recuperar o valor da combo ficaria assim..:
`variavel_inteira:= integer( cmbNomes.Items.Objects[index]);`

Espero ter compreendido seu problema corretamente e ter explicado de uma forma clara :)
Abraços :)